# Include a CKEditor Plugin in an Install Profile / Distribution

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, distributions, installation-profiles

I am working on an install profile that needs some CKEditor plugins. For example. the [template plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/templates). You can [add the module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_template) no problem:

```
composer require drupal/wysiwyg_templates
```

Getting the JS plugin seems to be a bit harder. There seem to be 3 options:

1. Using composer:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "ckeditor/templates",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "version": "4.5.7",
                "dist": {
                    "type": "zip",
                    "url": "http://download.ckeditor.com/templates/releases/templates_4.5.7.zip",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Using a manual install:

> Download a tarball from the CKEditor site and unpack it into the `web/sites/libraries` directory.

3. Ship plugins within the codebase:

Drupal core ships with some [libraries in its codebase](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/tree/8.5.x/core/assets/vendor), are distributions allowed to do that too? (In this case, CKEditor plugins are GPL code.)

---

The problem with **approach 1** is that all projects based on your distribution need to have that in their `composer.json` file too. If you wanted a couple of plugins, you how have to include an extra 12-or-so lines in every `composer.json` that uses your project. If you wish to add a new library you break all existing projects.

The problem with **approach 2** is that you're adding a manual setup step in addition to `composer install`. Very undesirable.

The problem with **approach 3** is that it might not be allowed, and you might have trouble getting contrib modules to find these libraries based on the install location in `vendor`. Still, it seems like the only option that might allow you to work around the boilerplate and manual download/update issues.

If there are any examples of a distribution handling this nicely that would be appreciated.